# Electronic ballast ratings

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

Hello I have a 4 bulb fixture that im working with. It currently is set up with one ballast for each bulb. I bought a philips EB-C 136 TL-D 220-240 ballast to go back. My bulbs are 18watts. The diagram says you can do either one 36 watt or 2 18 watt bulbs. So what happens if I just hook up one 18 watt. It will just be over driven and brighter, or does the ballast adjust?

Comment: You said your ballast does 2 - 18 watt lamps. Why wouldn't you just connect it to light two of the lamps? Then get another ballast for the other two lamps. Most older four tube fixtures have two ballasts.

Comment: There should be a connection diagram on the ballast. The ballast provides the spike to initiate the plasma then regulates the voltage to a specific level so just 1 lamp on a ballast rated for 2 it will run cooler and possibly last longer but the output from each lamp or 1 lamp will be the same.

Comment: Yes ArchonOSX, I was thinking that also why not just wire up 2 lamps and eliminate another of the cheap ballasts that are causing problems anyways. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every ballast is different.  There is no pattern or rule.  Sometimes the sales literature doesn't even agree with the data sheet - I've had to send ballasts back for that reason.

The data sheet (which is not the sales pamphlet or sometimes even the instruction sheet in the box) will list every supported bulb size, usually with wiring diagrams for each different configuration.

I don't see a data sheet for this ballast.  [This is as close](http://www.lighting.philips.com.sg/prof/electronic-control-gear/fluorescent/fluorescent-fixed-output-gear/eb-certalume-for-tl-d-lamps/913713199218_EU/product) as Google gets me.

They also seem to make a ballast for a single 18 watt bulb, [here](https://www.lighting.philips.com/main/prof/lighting-electronics/fluorescent/fluorescent-fixed-output-gear/eb-certalume-for-tl-d-lamps/913713199018_EU/product).  That's a bad sign.  Distributors don't like carrying a huge variety of ballasts, so manufacturers try to make ballasts work on as many configurations as possible.  The fact that they make a 1-18W ballast as well as a 1-36W, certainly suggests one *can't* do both jobs.

Comment: It's very likely that a 1x18W is cheaper to make than a 2x18W. I can definitely get my hands on both 1x28W T5 and 2x28W T5 ballasts.

Answer (score 0):

If the ballast has one set of wires that runs to the Gang Box and one set of wires that runs to the fixture it will only run one light if it has two identical sets that run from the ballast to the fixture it can run two lights

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).